# Does iOS 7 have issues with custom fonts + autolayout constraints?

Tags: ios, autolayout, ios-autolayout

I've spent many days trying to find out, why I had quite random autoLayout constraints errors on **iOS 7** (no problems on iOS 8 whatsoever).

Now it seems to me the problem **could be** when using custom fonts:

- UILabel with a custom font inside a container and pinned to the container with 0-0-0-0 (top, left, right, bottom)

Autolayout-constraints error was **always** about some **vertical** alignment issues.

So am I right about my assumption (NOTE: **no issues** on iOS 8)?

Comment: Can you show some picture showing the problem (and how it suppose to look).

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/X6CbS5k.png

Comment: Issues on iOS 7 stopped, when I changed the way each label (maybe even does not matter if custom font or factory font) is positioned inside container. If I fixed size of each label and centered it, there were no more problems on iOS 7.

Comment: I'm experimenting this myself.
Autolayout on IB does seem to have Vertical issues when resizing Labels to accommodate text. Either on iOS8 or iOS7